# stack all elements of list in R (including list in list)

Tags: r, list, stack

consider

```
mylist=list('a',c('aa','bb','cc'),'d')
```

I have two questions(I want to stack them in two ways):
First:
I want column output like

```
col1
a
aa
bb
cc
d
```

Second:
I want dataframe like

```
col1 col2 col3
a    NA   NA 
aa   bb   cc
d    NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is easy :

```
  data.frame(col1=unlist(mylist),stringsAsFactors=F)


              col1
  1              a
  2             aa
  3             bb
  4             cc
  5              d
```

Second one:

```
t(sapply(mylist, "[", 1:3))

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "a"  NA   NA  
 [2,] "aa" "bb" "cc"
 [3,] "d"  NA   NA
```